# Changing the proxy server settings for Toggl Desktop

Tags: proxy

The time tracking software "Toggl Desktop" appears to be sending a connection request to our old proxy server every 3 seconds, and it's failing. I'm not getting any errors, and the app is working, but I had a call from one of our system admin guys wondering what's happening.

I can't even remember setting the proxy server, and can't see how to change it. How can I fix the proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

Log Out of the software, and there is a proxy settings option available on the Log In page.